# ошибки при запуске проекта Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

села прописывать вьюхи и урлы, часмть прописала, в результате при попытке запустить проект по команде python3 manage.py runserver получаю ошибки

```
(nata&paints) yslepenko@US131:~/PycharmProjects/nata&paints/root$ python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/nata&paints/root/root/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/it-blog/nata&paints/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/nata&paints/root/blog/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import _list, create, details, edit, delete
  File "/home/yslepenko/PycharmProjects/nata&paints/root/blog/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .forms import PostForm, PostForm2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.forms'
```

Comment: Самую важную часть ошибки забыли показать

Comment: Во-первых, любой текст, в том числе и текст ошибки, следует выкладывать именно **текстом, а не картинкой**, а во-вторых, как уже заметил @andreymal, **самая важная и информативная часть описания ошибки, как правило, содержится к конце**.

Comment: Покажите вашу ошибку полностью!

Comment: под вашим вопросом есть кнопка править, скопируйте полный текст ошибки и вставьте в свой вопрос.

Comment: @andreymal добавила

Comment: `No module named 'blog.forms'` а есть то хоть формы у вас в проекте ?

Comment: накосячила в структуре, в Templates засунула папку из рута, поправила и все прошло

Answer (score 1):

накосячила в структуре, в Templates засунула папку из рута, поправила и все прошло